# SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition - Login Fail for User (computer Name)/Guest

Tags: windows, sql-server

Subject:
SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition, windows XP
Log-in fail for odbc sql server user computer name/guest

I am connecting for several computer with the VB6 application with following connection string
"PROVIDER=MSDASQL;driver={SQL Server};server=Computer Name.;uid=;pwd=;database=Test Name;"

BUT, just Three Computer not Log-in. This three (connected with each other) are completely separate in other Room.

I checked all possible options. Besides, which option is missing???
Please Help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you can log in with some computers using that connection string, then it looks to be correct, so your potential problems here are:

- The computers do not have network connectivity to the SQL server
- The computers do not have the required SQL Server driver available
- There are firewall issues.

It would be useful if you could provide any error message you may be getting.